# univalence and indiscernibility

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Given $A, B: U$ (where $U$ is a universe), define $\mathsf{Indis}(A, B)$ to be $\prod_{Q: U \rightarrow U} Q(A) \leftrightarrow Q(B)$. (This just says that $A$ and $B$ are in a certain sense indiscernible.)

(i) Without univalence, is something like $A \simeq B \rightarrow \mathsf{Indis}(A,B)$ provable? I assume the answer is no.

(ii) What about if we just ask, of any $Q:U \rightarrow U$, whether $A \simeq B \rightarrow (Q(A) \leftrightarrow Q(B))$ is true? (We do not require the proof to be 'uniform' in $Q$, in such a way that this would produce an affirmative answer to the first question.)

Apologies as always if this question is somehow confused.

Answer (score 1):

On one hand, univalence clearly implies (i), since if $A \simeq B$, then $A = B$, so $A$ and $B$ are indistinguishable in your sense.

On the other hand, $\mathsf{Indis}(A, B)$ implies $A = B$ (using $Q(X) := A = X$ and reflexivity), so (i) is (logically) equivalent to the statement that $A \simeq B \to A = B$.

This latter statement is sometimes called weak univalence ([e.g. here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/homotopytypetheory/j2KBIvDw53s/YTDK4D0NFQAJ)). As far as I'm aware, it's still open whether this implies full univalence.